# Did Hibernate 6.2.x change the way it generates DDL?

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a project that has an initialization SQL script.  It does very simple things like:

```sql
INSERT INTO FROB VALUES(1, 'Foo', 2);
```

(I am aware it is bad practice not to list the columns into which you are inserting values. Let's pretend for the moment this is out of my control.)

In all Hibernate versions prior to the 6.2 line, this script has worked fine.

With an upgrade from Hibernate 6.1.7.Final to Hibernate 6.2.7.Final, the SQL script reliably fails with errors indicating that, for example, '`Foo`' cannot be converted to an integer, suggesting that the ordering of columns in the Hibernate-generated DDL has changed. Here is an excerpted error stack from a run that happens to use the H2 database:

```
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: Data conversion error converting "Foo" [22018-220]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
    at org.h2.value.ValueStringBase.getInt(ValueStringBase.java:133)
    at org.h2.value.Value.convertToInt(Value.java:1596)
```

I've read the [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#ddl-changes) but it makes no mention of this sort of thing.

The schema is being generated courtesy of the usual ordinary boring Jakarta Persistence properties:

```xml
<properties>
    <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    <property name="jakarta.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/init_script.sql"/>
    <!-- etc. -->
</properties>
```

There are no other fancy settings.

Is there some way to influence the results of the generated DDL in Hibernate 6.2.x?

(I see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17065 that seems like perhaps it is in the general area of this problem, though I'm not using composite primary keys or anything like that. But thankfully it does seem like perhaps Hibernate 6.2.x did something rather major in the area of DDL generation.)

(Indeed, it would seem, they did: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.2.7/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/boot/model/relational/ColumnOrderingStrategyStandard.java)